# Global constants in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm refactoring some of my older PS scripts to a) improve them b) clean up c) modularize.

In the script I'm working now there are 10-15 functions that work on specific directory - let's call it work directory. Currently it's defined globally and loaded from a config file; it never changes after initialization (does that make it a constant?).

I want to wrap some of the functions in a separate module. The question is: should I rewrite them so the variable is passed explicitly as a parameter, or can I leave it as is, with the assumption that every script I use this module (library?) in will have this variable initialized? If the latter, how to make sure the module can "detect" the variable is uninitialized and throw some error?

And, last but not least, currently it's just a variable - should I use some specific construct so that it's obvious it is global, and not to be modified?

Comment: Is there _any_ legitimate circumstance under which the user can/should override/influence this value?

Comment: No, it's static, except for the fact it's loaded from config file and not defined in the code itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> should I rewrite them so the variable is passed explicitly as a parameter

As long as there's no legitimate use case for overriding it in a single call, I wouldn't pass it as a parameter.

If your functions are packaged as a module, I'd strongly recommend utilizing *module-scoped* variables rather than globals.

Assuming you're talking about a script module, this is as simple as:

```
Set-Variable -Scope Script -Name ModuleTargetDirectory -Value $config.TargetDirectory
```

from inside the module file or a module function that runs during import (the `script:` scope is the same as module-scope inside a module), and then in the consuming functions:

```
function Get-Something
{
    # ...
    $targetDirectory = $script:ModuleTargetDirectory
    # ...
}
```

Or wrap the entire config storage in a private helper method:

```
# don't export this function
function Get-MyModuleConfig
{
  # assuming we stored a dictionary or custom object with the config options in a module-scoped variable named `config`
  return $script:config
}
```

And then always just call `$config = Get-MyModuleConfig` in the `begin` block of functions that need access to the config data